# Using count vectorizer only

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am getting the same results while using any of the 2 vectorizer:

```
vect=CountVectorizer(min_df=1,  token_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]+')
vX = vect.fit_transform(movies['genres'])
df3=pd.DataFrame(vX.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```

Is there any case when I will "have to" use Binary Analyzer instead of count vectorizer?

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mym=mlb.fit_transform(movies['genres'].str.split('|'))
ndf2=pd.DataFrame(mym, columns=mlb.classes_)
```

Or is there any difference in df3 and ndf2 that I may have missed? My question is, can I use only Count Vectroizer?

Comment: When using separately exactly like this, there should not be any differences, given that you give attention to what the other default parameters do. Like the `'lowercase'` in `CountVectorizer` will lower case all the input strings by default, whereas `MLB` will not. But you may not use `MLB` inside a pipeline without some extra effort. Is there a specfic reason to use only the `CountVectorizer` ?

Comment: @VivekKumar because as per Zen of Python "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." I prefer to use consistent methods across scripts.

Comment: Well then these two things you are using are meant for different purposes. If your only goal is to get a k-hot encoded representation from the `movies['genres']`, then `MLB` is the designated tool. `CountVectorizer` is supposed to work on text, on which it will do some pre-processing, tokenization, etc and then get the counts. That is an overkill here.